# MS Teams | Accessibility Insight | Dual Monitor

Tags: ui-automation, microsoft-teams, dpi, multiple-monitors, accessibility-insights

**Objective**: Accessibility behavior of MS Teams on Dual Monitor, with Monitors setup at different scales, example 100% and 125%, with 1920*1080 resolution. The tool I use is Accessibility Insight.

**Problem**: Accessibility Insight is unable to locate the MS Teams' Elements correctly when I launch Teams App in Monitor with 100% scale, which is also my Primary Monitor, and move it to the monitor with 125% scale. I see the position of the identified Element is off by about 280 from the Top. I also see that Left seems to be off by about a factor of 1.25, which I presume could be due to Scaling.
If I work on single Monitor with 125% (or any other scale), Accessibility Insight works nicely on MS Teams.

**What I Read/Understand**: I understand MS Teams is a Per Monitor DPI Aware App and so is Accessibility Insight. If I enable GDI scaling, reading [Improve High DPI Experience](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/05/19/improving-high-dpi-experience-gdi-based-desktop-apps/) , I do see that Accessibility Insight is able to locate the Element as it should. Further, Accessibility Insight works well on "Display Settings" itself (SystemSettings.exe process), which is also Per Monitor DPI Aware. It makes me presume that Per Monitor Awareness in MS Teams is not correctly implemented.

**Questions**:

1. Is my presumption correct that MS Teams doesn't work as expected on Dual/multi Monitors that is, it scales up or down correctly in Dual monitors with different scale factors?
2. Is there anyway to get Accessibility Insight to work correctly on MS Teams without changing the GDI Scaling/Overriding High DPI Scaling of MS Teams?
3. Is there a challenge itself with Accessibility Insight running on Electron Application? I observe similar issue with Slack.

[Edit] Added result of using Windows Automation API

[image]

The Monitor where Teams runs is at 125% and 1920x1080. While my demo app is marked as Per Monitor DPI Aware and runs on Monitor 100%, 1920x1080. Both the Monitors are of 14 inches in size. The result shows Root [Teams' Main Window] Element's Left and Top location as well as location of Left and Top of "Search" box, at top of the title bar in Teams App, that Automation API retrieves. As per Microsoft's documentation, Automation API retrieves Physical coordinates. Observations

1. Physical Location of Mouse says X:2455 and Y:10
2. Left and Top location of Element Search Box from Automation API comes out as 2935 & 280 respectively.
3. Value of 2935, when scaled down by 1.25 is 2348, which matches Physical Location of Mouse on Search box when I run my App in System DPI Aware or DPI Unaware mode. So the Left Coordinate in Per Monitor Mode is scaled up version of Left Coordinate in System Aware or Unaware mode.
4. **I cannot draw any correlation with anything to Top value of 280**

Answer (score 2):

We investigated this on the Accessibility Insights end of things and it looks to be an issue with Teams. We were able to verify this with Magnifier; we configured it to track keyboard focus and found that it is inconsistent in identifying location of elements as well (indicating a Teams problem). As in, some controls were correct in being tracked while others were not.

Note: this was even without dual monitor setup.